# LibreOffice 5 refuses to start

Tags: permissions, libreoffice

I've seen the question asked a number of times but everywhere I checked it there was only a workaround offered (delete libreoffice directory in ~/.config/username). So I have to do it after each restart, and the styles I change never get saved into my profile.

The fatal error I get is

The application cannot be started
User installation could not be completed

I gather it has something to do with the permissions, but I am very new to Linux (Ubuntu 15.04 in my case) and need assistance here.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include the output of command `ls -ld ~/.config/{,libreoffice}` (executed in a terminal) please?

Answer (score 0):

Steeldriver, thanks for your attention to my questions. As expected, there was nothing really serious about the problem. Some hours ago the system suggested I download updates including some for LibreOffice, which I did. After that, the error message I got became more verbose and clear: LO informed me of insufficient permissions for the .config/libreoffice folder. Turned out it was owned by root. I ran

```
sudo chown -R username:group ~/.config/libreoffice
```

(replace username and group with your actual username and group name)

and the problem disappeared.

I hope my reply will be of help to someone looking for help as numerous other extended replies were to me.

Thanks!